# Limits of an increasing function

Tags: limits, functions, proof-writing

Let $a<b$ and let $f: [a,b] \to R$ be an increasing function.

I'm asked to provide an example where $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)$ does not equal

$$\inf\{\,f(x) \; | \;x \in [a,b]\,\},$$

and I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is going on in this situation and was wondering if anyone can enlighten me.

**Background**

Prior to this question I was asked to prove that there exists an $S$ in $R$ such that

$$ S = \inf\{\,f(x)\; |\; x \in (a,b]\,\}.$$

I used the fact that $F$ is an increasing function and showed $F$ is bounded from below and therefore must have an infimum.

Then I was asked to prove that the $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)$ exists, and is equal to S.

I showed this by definition of limit, using the fact that if $F$ is bounded from below, then there exists $L$ such that $L$ is less than or equal to $F(x)$.

I have a feeling my professor wants me to use the things I showed above to find the example to the initial question, but I just can't connect the dots…

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest you start using mathjax to typing your questions. Eg see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks I will try to improve my mathjax skills from post to post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Jump discontinuity]

This is a picture of what can happen at the endpoint (what *needs* to happen, in fact).

1. Remember to keep your counterexamples as simple as possible!
2. For the limit part ($L$ is the unfilled circle), you can perhaps use the sequential definition of limit, with the version of the completeness axiom that applies to monotonic sequences.

Answer (score -2):

The big difference between the two infimums is that one includes $a$ while the other doesn't. To take advantage of it we use cases. For example,
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}g(x), &x \neq a\\
-1 &x=  a\end{cases}
$$
What will happen if $g(x) > -1\ \forall x \in (a,b]$?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I understand that it's practically the same answer as @{Good Boy} but it wasn't posted when I was typing and it provides a slightly different way to view the question?